# How to create dynamic newsletter in Asp.net for system.net.mail

Tags: asp.net, system.net.mail

i am creating an application for newsletter that sends bulk mail to clients.i need to create newsletter with dynamically selected format like dynamic images(header/footer) and reciepant name etc.i am not getting any idea to create html message to send in smtpclient.send function...

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.From =new MailAddress("mailid@gmail.com");
    msg.Subject = "To check working";
    msg.Body="<html><body><header image>...content...<footer image></body></html>";
```

i want to get header image,content,footer image path to generate at runtime from database.
any code or idea is required that how can i get that html dynamically...

thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at http://newsletter.codeplex.com/ project.